# How To use Tensoflow TFlite Models in flutter

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have developed a model in python and exported it to TFLite format but I tried to integrate it into my flutter application all in vain. The plugins available at pub.dev that deal with tflite models are all deprecated and therefore cant run with flutter v2. How can I overgo this? Thanks.

Comment: What packages did you try?

Comment: i tried tflite but its deprecated its not updated to flutter V2

Answer (score 0):

#### This worked for me!

Follow [This great tutorial](https://morioh.com/p/cf2128b9a231). It explains step by step how to use your tflite models in your flutter apps